# Как построить график зависимости интенсивности от длины волны для спектра?

Tags: python, r, график, физика, поиск-программ

Нужно построить график зависимости интенсивности, от длины волны для спектра. Также, нужно по пикам графика определить длины волн.

Мне Нужно это сделать для двух случаев:

1. Когда сплошной спектр(картинка внизу);
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Когда каждая спектральная линия отдельно фотографируется,то есть имеется семейство линий для которых нужно построить график.

С помощью какой программы я это могу сделать?

Comment: может python + matplotlib

Comment: Я искал для питона пакеты, которые помогли мне это сделать, но ничего не нашел. Конечно это можно в  ручную  написать, но это очень долго.

Comment: @Zero149, вы можете привести пример данных?

Comment: Как я понимаю любой график строится на каких-либо данных. Построить можно и в Excel, была бы таблица.
Тогда уточняю вопрос: требуется готовый набор данных, содержащий интенсивность и длину волны? Правильно понято?

Comment: Результат должен быть таким?
 -
 https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/Spectra.Classical%26Function.jpg

Comment: Да должен быть таким.